# ERROR CS0120 Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, método o propiedad 'Control.Show()' no estaticos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, show

Una ayuda pls cuando intento poner el codigo Show para mostrar otro formulario "Form2.Show()" me sale ese error y no tengo idea por que :(

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte se necesita más detalles de tu problema, considera añadir un [mcve] donde expliques con detalle el problema, el comportamiento actual y el resultado esperado. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Para mostrar un nuevo formulario debes crear una variable que sea del tipo del formulario que deseas construir e instanciarla:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Show();
```

Como ves aquí la **variable frm2** es de tipo **Form2**, por tanto creas el objeto y posteriormente invocas el **método Show** para mostrar el formulario.